# withContext<Unit> what it does? Coroutines

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am researching blueprints sample by google 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-live-kotlin
 in datasource layer they use 2 different ways to handle suspend function :

```
withContext<Unit>(ioDispatcher) {
  ....
}
```

and such:

```
withContext(ioDispatcher) {
    ...
}
```

what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

`withContext` [has a generic argument](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html), which specifies the return type of the lambda that you pass in. If the lambda doesn't return anything, it would be better to explicitly use `Unit` returns type, in this case there will be a warning, if your lambda returns something by mistake.

```
// No warnings, the result has Int type, which has been inferred automatically
val result = withContext(ioDispatcher) { 123 }

// "The expression is unused" warning, because the lambda should't return anything
val result = withContext<Unit>(ioDispatcher) { 123 }
```